# Two TextFields in tableview, all on scrollview, disappear when keyboard comes up iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uitextfield

In My Login View I Have E-mail and Password textfields in a grouped tableview with two cells.  I added the two textfields programmatically:

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    _cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    _cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    _cell.backgroundColor =  [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:1];
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        _emailTxtFld = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 7, 277, 34)];
        _emailTxtFld.placeholder = @"E-mail";
        _emailTxtFld.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:15];
        _emailTxtFld.clearsOnBeginEditing = YES;
        [_emailTxtFld setDelegate:self];
        [_emailTxtFld setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress];
        [_cell.contentView addSubview:_emailTxtFld];

    }

    if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        _passwordTxtFld = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 7, 277, 34)];
        _passwordTxtFld.placeholder = @"Password";
        _passwordTxtFld.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:15];
        _passwordTxtFld.secureTextEntry = YES;
        [_passwordTxtFld setDelegate:self];
        _passwordTxtFld.clearsOnBeginEditing = YES;
        [_cell.contentView addSubview:_passwordTxtFld];
    }

    return _cell;
    }
```

This is all on a scrollview.  When a textfield is touched, the keyboard comes up, and the the scrollview comes up with the rest of the view being viewable by scrolling.  The problem is the textfields and the table view and the text that I type disappear, when i touch inside them to edit them.  I can still see the autocorrect, and after I've typed something and the keyboard has returned everything is back to normal and I can see the text I've entered.

If I comment out everything in my keyboardDidShow Method, then the table view and textfields do not disappear.  But obviously I want to keep that line in.

```
    -(void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)notif
    {
       _logScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 245);// This line commented out stops the problem


    }

    -(void)keyboardDidHide:(NSNotification *)notif
    {
        _logScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
    }
```

Let me know if I need to give you some more code.
Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Once I get over ten reputation, I'll add images

Comment: It is probably scrolling out of view.  Can you scroll up or down and "find" the text fields?

Comment: Yeah, your right I think.  I wasn't able to see the textfields anywhere though.  My answer below solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a tableview inside the scrollview? UITableView is already a child class of UIScrollView. You should not have one inside the other.

Another thing: you have this:

```
_emailTxtFld.clearsOnBeginEditing = YES;
```

and

```
_passwordTxtFld.clearsOnBeginEditing = YES;
```

Which means that they will clear once the textfield becomes the first responder. I dont really understand what is happening after the keyboard dismisses. Can you give a little detail about what is disappearing?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve my problem.  I don't know the right wording, but I just created a variable from my tableview that I had already created in IB and in the keyboardDidShow method I made the frame stay where it was like this:

```
-(void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)notif
{
    _logScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 245);

    _tableViewWTxtFlds.frame =  CGRectMake(8, 153, 304, 79);


}

-(void)keyboardDidHide:(NSNotification *)notif
{
    _logScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);

    _tableViewWTxtFlds.frame =  CGRectMake(8, 153, 304, 79);
}
```

Apparently the tableview was moving out of my view, that's what I'm guessing was wrong if this fixes it.  Thanks for checking out my question.